# Equal to operation not working on a field with updated collation

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, collation

I was trying to convert an existing `varchar` column with a `unique` index on it to a  `case sensitive` column. So to do this, I updated the collation of the particular column.

- Previous value: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
- Current value: utf8mb4_bin

Now I have a row in my table `TEST_TABLE` with `test_column` value is `abcd`.

When I try to run a simple query like `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE test_column = 'abcd';` it returns no result.

However when I try `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE test_column LIKE 'abcd';` it returns the data correctly.

Also when I try `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE BINARY test_column = 'abcd';` it returns the data correctly.

One more thing I tried was creating a duplicate of the table with column collation set as `utf8mb4_bin` while creating itself and then copy all data from original table. Then the query `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE test_column = 'abcd';` is working alright.

So this seems to be a problem with `BINARY` conversion. Is there any solution to this or Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE test_column = 'abcd' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;`

Comment: This will require me to edit existing queries, right. My doubt is that it should be working without the COLLATE option in queries ?

Comment: Explicit collation specifying makes the query independent of the settings. It will do strictly those which you tell. If it is not used then you rely on default settings. Which may fail, and you see it in practice now.

Comment: okay, is there a performance hit when using explicit collation ? I have some frequently running queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with MySQL. The steps I followed to resolve this is as follows:

1. dropped the unique index on the column
2. change the collation of the column
3. created the unique index again

Now it is working as expected. It seems MySQL didn't rebuild unique index when collation was changed. However the above steps solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

How did you change the collation?  There are about 4 ways that you might think to do it.  Most do something different.

Probably `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO COLLATION utf8mb4_bin` was what you needed.

Why "bin"?  You want to match case and accents?  That is "abcd" != "Abcd"?